# Problem reconnecting mailbox in exchange

Tags: exchange-2007

I am trying to reconnect a mail box to an exchange user that was deleted from the AD.

When i follow the directions and go into exchange manager i see the users mail box listed in the disconnected mail boxes, and i can start the process but when the screen pops up to select a user to connect it to there are none listed, and trying to change the OU that it is looking in does no good.

Does anyone know why the user selection lists would be empty?

This is exchange 2007 on Windows SBS server.

Answer (score 1):

There's no Exchanged enabled Users without Mailboxes.

Comment: Aparrently, and there seems to be some type of filtering going on in the SBS. I had to create a user in the AD console not the SBS console to get something to show up.

Comment: In other words, you had to create a user in Active Directory without a mailbox, then attach the disconnected mailbox to that new user, correct?

Comment: @Bart, Yeah, but the user has to have Exchange attributes. The easiest way is to right click the user, select Exchange Tasks, and create an e-mail address for the user.